# Connect VS 2013 with SQL server 2008 or 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013

im new to ASP.net

my simple question how can i connect SQL server with VS 2013 
so that i can create my Database in SQL Server by using **Code first Approach**

because i have have to schedule stored procedures in my database for my application

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your database by using the Server Explorer.

VS 2013 > View > Server Explorer

Click on the Plug Item (Connect to Database)

[Great Tutorial for CodeFirst](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but sir , but i want to create a new database by using code first approach in SQL server , there is no database already created to in SQL server